# Accessing a remote kubernetes cluster with grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, grafana, amazon-route53, kops

I have a Grafana running on an EC2 instance. I installed my Kubernetes cluster k8s.mydomain.com on AWS using kops. I wanted to monitor this cluster with Grafana. Entering the below URL for Prometheus data source and the admin username and password from `kops get secrets kube --type secret -oplaintext`  in grafana returned an error.

https://api.k8s.afaquesiddiqui.com/api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/services/prometheus-k8s:9090/proxy/graph#!/role?namespace=default

I also tried the kops add-on for [prometheus](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/addons.md) but I wasn't able to access grafana using the following URL:

https://api.k8s.mydomain.com/api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/services/grafana:3000/proxy/#!/role?namespace=default

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs that you specified are proxy endpoints so they are accessed through a proxy that is usually set up on your client with:

```
kubectl proxy
```

I supposed you could access it from the outside if you expose your kube-apiserver to the outside which highly unrecommended.

If you want to access the endpoint from the outside you usually do it through the [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which in your first case is `prometheus-k8s` on port `9090` and in the second case is `grafana` on port `3000`.  You didn't provide whether the services are exposed through a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) so the endpoint will vary depending on how it's exposed.  You can find out with:

```
kubectl get svc
```

Comment: I was trying to connect with ClusterIP. Sorry, I'm new to kuberenetes. Anyways, I'm now able to connect with nodeport but I was wondering if grafana will display only the metrics of one node as I'm only connected to onenode right now.

Comment: No problem. I believe Prometheus scrapes all your pods